# How to update Android APIs?

Tags: android, sdk

I have API upto 11. Now I want to work on API 14, so please tell me how to take updated remaining higher API 12, 13, 14 etc.

Comment: You need not update from 11 to 12, then 13 then 14.. U can update whatever package you want directly from 11 to 14. Please open **Android SDK Manager**.

Comment: Read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). You should accept some of the answers to your questions. BTW as others have told, you have to install the required SDK packages using Android SDK Manager. You may have to update ADT plugin in Eclipse also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse IDE then Click on Windows-> Android Sdk Manager->this opens a dialog in which all shows all versions which are installed or Not installed-> then check mark on which you want to install-> click on install packages button-> then click on Accept and install the same.

Answer (score 0):

Open you Andorid SDK manager and update to the relevant packages from within eclipse